# Adding new members while iterating a hash with "each"

Tags: hash, perl, perl5.10

In perl 5.10.1 is it ok to add new members to a hash while iterating through it with the `each` operator?

Smth. like in this code (preparing data for Google charts), where I have a hash of hashes of arrays and I am trying to move the last element of each array:

```
sub split_aclr($) {
        my $csvData = shift;

        while (my ($csv, $href) = each %$csvData) {
                next unless $csv =~ /_ACLR_/i;
                my $len = scalar @{$href->{MEASUREMENT}};

                if ($len > 1 && $href->{MEASUREMENT}->[$len - 1] eq 'CARRIER_CHANNEL') {
                        while (my ($key, $arr) = each %$href) {
                                my $moved = pop @$arr;
                                $csvData{$csv . '_CARRIER_CHANNEL'} = {$key => [ $moved ]};
                        }
                }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not generally safe to add or remove entries of a hash while iterating it using `each`. If you want to do so, it might be best to save an explicit list of keys you want to iterate to an array, and loop over that.

Instead of

```
while (my $k, $v) = each %hash) {
  $hash{"foo_$k"} = $v;
}
```

do

```
my @keys = keys %hash;
for my $k (@keys) {
  my $v = $hash{$k};
  $hash{"foo_$k"} = $v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it okay to omit `@keys` in your code and just use `for my $k (keys %hash)` ?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber Yes, in this case the `@keys` can be omitted. I used an extra variable to make the copying of the key list clear. However, one cannot use `foreach` loops if one would modify the array that is being iterated.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't safe. If you do it, you will get a warning: "Use of each() on hash after insertion without resetting hash iterator results in undefined behavior."

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `each()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/functions/each.html) is pretty clear on this.

> If you add or delete elements of a hash while you're iterating over
>   it, you may get entries skipped or duplicated, so don't.